# Eclipse + Git - How to get toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I've got Eclipse 3.7.2 installed and working fine. I installed the git plugins (see below).

[image: My installed software]

Right clicking my active project and clicking on "Team" gives me the options to pull/push/commit and more.

I have set my git executeable to msysgit (C git).

The docs told me that to add git to the toolbar I should look in `Window->Customize Perspective...`, but I couldn't anything related to git there, not even under the "Command Groups Availability" section.

**How do I add push, pull & commit buttons to my Eclipse toolbar?**

[image: no Git in there]

Comment: Do you still have the issue when you are in "Git Perspective" ? Ie do you see git when customizing *that* perspective?

Comment: I can't find that perspective?

Comment: That (unable to find the Git perspective) would be a good sign of the plugin being incorrectly installed.

Comment: This is quite an old question, but there is newer/better/easier answer to it now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240031/git-cannot-be-made-visible-because-all-of-its-children-are-in-unavailable-acti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing worked and I had begun getting an unrelated error on startup with a troubleshooting step requiring reinstall.

This time I downloaded [Eclipse for Mobile Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-mobile-developers/junor), and since then I have added my other packages and it's all working, but clicking the commit thing and clicking the arrow to merge  my changes (with comment) results in nothing.

It isn't committed nor is an error given.

Answer (score 21):

Stumbled on this answer, but found this works:

Install the Egit plugin, add the Git command group in Customize Perspective|Command Groups Availability, not the (pretty much useless) "Team", then [check "Git" in Customize Perspective|Tool Bar Visibility](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#egitconfiguration_toolbar)

[image: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/images/xgit_toolbar10.png.pagespeed.ic.7xMapnhWrH.png]

Answer (score 3):

First install EGit from http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates. Then you should find the Git command group and be able to activate it. msysgit isn't integrated with Eclipse.

See "[Activating the Git toolbar](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#egitconfiguration_toolbar) "

[image: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/images/xgit_toolbar10.png.pagespeed.ic.7xMapnhWrH.png]

Comment: I already have EGit, but I'm not getting the option. (using Eclipse Juno now)

Answer (score 0):

1. install a fresh copy of eclipse with a new fresh workplace
2. install egit
3. show egit in toolbar (from customise perspective, etc....)
4. copy `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi` from the fresh installed workplace into your current workplace

you'll loose some position settings of the layout, but most of the settings will be kept, and most important you'll have egit in toolbar in your current workplace.

if you like you can analyse/diff the file `workbench.xmi` and see what you have to set to get the toolbar; for me it was enough (most likely workplace was from previous versions of eclipse, and egit/eclipse does not update this xml file)