# 'git' cannot be made visible because all of its children are in unavailable action sets

Tags: eclipse, git, perspective

I have this problem and I have no idea how to get the Git section on the toolbar. The image below shows the specific error :

[image: git problem]

Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**In the "Action Set Availability" tick "Git" and "Git Navigation Actions"**

[image]

**Then in "Tool Bar Visibility" tick "Git"**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This message has been introduced in Eclispe 4.4 ([commit 427558b](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/commit/427558bf550c224067871fc7b3fcac09d14cc3c8#diff-893bcd11c6fc8f9c4215fb47e4c95b49R167) of [`eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/)), replacing "command groups" by "[action sets](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_an_action_set%3F)".

See "[How do I make my action set visible?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_my_action_set_visible%3F)"

> the user can always have the last say by customizing perspectives (`Window > Customize Perspective`).
>   From here, the user can turn on or off any action sets for the current perspective. This will override all the other mechanisms for defining action set visibility.